# Help understanding problem about critical points (multivariable)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, polar-coordinates, maxima-minima

> [image]

I have a question on this problem. As you can see the solutions are given above. My question is when $N = 2$, when finding critical points. I get, that  the gradient equals zero when

$$x = 0,\: y^2 +x^2 = 1$$

If $x = 0$ I can have $y = -1$ and $y = 1$ (also $y = 0$ but this is when derivative DNE) .

However I don't understand how the solution gets to $(\cos a, \sin a)$. I understand that
$$\sin^2(x) +\cos^2(x)= 1$$
However, I do not know how to interpret or get from $y^2 +x^2 = 1$ to using polar coordinates.

Moreover, I'm totally lost when it calculates the maximum and minimum because I don't understand why it doesn't evaluate points like $(0,1)$, $(0,-1)\dots$

I think I need to understand how can I relate this problem with points of the form $(\cos a, \sin a)$ and from there how to calculate the critical points. Because right know I'm very confused.

Thanks !

Comment: Wait! You're taking multivariable calculus and you don't know that all the points on the unit circle can be represented as $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ for some value of $\theta$? How do you define the trigonometric functions, then? (This is actually totally irrelevant to the problem at hand, since the function is a function of $\|x\|$ only.)

Comment: I'm sorry but I know I'm not very good at this and I haven't been able to go to class this semester due to some familiar problems so I probably do lack some basic concepts and I don't really follow you. Could you explain it to me please ?

Comment: Maybe you miscalculated the gradient, because the book states that  all points satisfying $x^2+y^2=1$ are critical points. I'm glad to help you with that if you want to share your work with us.